# Method chaining in ruby

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation, method-chaining

I want to build an API client that has an interface similar to rails active record. I want the  consumers to be able to chain methods and after the last method is chained, the client requests a url based on the methods called. So it's method chaining with some lazy evaluation. I looked into [Active Record](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord) but this is very complicated (spawning proceses, etc).

Here is a toy example of the sort of thing I am talking about. You can chain as many 'bar' methods together as you like before calling 'get', like this:

```
puts Foo.bar.bar.get # => 'bar,bar'
puts Foo.bar.bar.bar.get # => 'bar,bar,bar'
```

I have successfully implemented this, but I would rather not need to call the 'get' method. So what I want is this:

```
puts Foo.bar.bar # => 'bar,bar'
```

But my current implementation does this:

```
puts Foo.bar.bar #=> [:bar, :bar]
```

I have thought of overriding array methods like `each` and `to_s` but I am sure there is a better solution.

How would I chain the methods and know which was the last one so I could return something like the string returned in the `get` method?

Here is my current implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Bar
  def get(args)
    # does a request to an API and returns things but this will do for now.
    args.join(',') 
  end
end

class Foo < Array
  def self.bar
    @q = new
    @q << :bar
    @q
  end

  def bar
    self << :bar
    self
  end

  def get
    Bar.new.get(self)
  end
end
```

Also see: [Ruby Challenge - Method chaining and Lazy Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632702/ruby-challenge-method-chaining-and-lazy-evaluation)

Comment: Curious to know why using `inject` wouldn't be simpler.

Comment: @Denis - Obviously it would in this case. The question is however how to write the general class supporting method chaining with lazy execution. What this class does isn't really important here.

Comment: This is closed because it's unclear what I am asking but I have a correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How it works with activerecord is that the relation is a wrapper around the array, delegating any undefined method to this internal array (called `target`). So what you need is to start with a BasicObject instead of Object:

```
class Foo < BasicObject
```

then you need to create internal variable, to which you will delegate all the methods:

```
  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    reload! unless loaded?
    @target.send(*args, &block)
  end

  def reload!
    # your logic to populate target, e.g:
    @target = @counter
    @loaded = true
  end

  def loaded?
    !!@loaded
  end
```

To chain methods, your methods need to return new instance of your class, e.g:

```
def initialize(counter=0)
  @counter = counter
end

def bar
  _class.new(@counter + 1)
end

private

# BasicObject does not define class method. If you want to wrap your target 
# completely (like ActiveRecord does before rails 4), you want to delegate it 
# to @target as well. Still you need to access the instance class to create 
# new instances. That's the way (if there are any suggestion how to improve it,
# please comment!)
def _class
  (class << self; self end).superclass
end
```

Now you can check it in action:

```
p Foo.new.bar.bar.bar      #=> 3
(f = Foo.new) && nil       # '&& nil' added to prevent execution of inspect             
                           # object in the console , as it will force @target 
                           # to be loaded

f.loaded?                  #=> false
puts f                     #=> 0
f.loaded?                  #=> true
```

Comment: It works! Much appreciated. I added a self.bar method so I could call Foo.bar and I will tidy my work up and apply it to my requirements. This is a great help. Thanks again.

Comment: `reload!` method populates the target and is the reason why you can say this object is lazy evaluated. Reload is only called when the values of target are needed and till then target is empty. However, when target is populated reload will not repopulate target (it's caching results), if youw ant to make it to be relaoded, you'll need to call it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

A (very simple, maybe simplistic) option would be to implement the to_s method - as it is used to "coerce" to string (for instance in a puts), you could have your specific "this is the end of the chain" code there.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. But it might be counter intuitive if the sub class overwrites some methods of it's parents but not others.

Comment: Agreed - as said, a crude option. I try to avoid too much meta programming when I can avoid it. But if you can't, @BroiSatse answer is probably better suited.